# icu-config getting static library flags

Tags: linux, gcc, icu

how to get static library flags for icu. Using icu-config .

If I run `icu-config --ldflags`

It links with dynamic library. I want to link against static library. How can I get static flag using `icu-config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if ICU was built for static libraries only, then icu-config should output the arguments for static libs. There's no option to select static libraries if both are available. You could file a bug on this.

What would be better is to use something like `pkg-config --static icu-uc --libs` but that does not seem to work either. You could file a bug on this.